# Update dictionary with items from a list

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I have a dictionary that I would like to update with items from a list. The list has items that are scraped from a website. How can I add the list items to the dictionary along with individual key names?

I am stumped on how to suffix the `Copy` key with a serialized sequence; additionally I would like all scraped items to be logged not just the last item in the list.

Note: Scraped items can be prefixed with any string

```
for item in scraped_items:
    dict['Copy '] = item  # Copy key should include a number suffix, e.g., 'Copy 0, Copy 1' and log all scraped items

# current output: {'locale': 'some place', 'Copy': <p>Second copy block</p>, 'title': 'some site'}
```

Scraped items:

```
[<p>First copy block</p>, <p>Second copy block</p>]
<type 'list'>
```

Current dictionary:

```
{
    "locale": "some place",
    "title": "some site"
}
```

Expected dictionary:

```
{
    "locale": "some place",
    "title": "some site",
    "Copy 0": "<p>First copy block</p>",
    "Copy 1": "<p>Second copy block</p>"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the indices of the list instead of the items themselves.

```
for i in range(len(scraped_items)):
    dict[f'Copy {i}'] = scraped_items[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `enumerate` as well

```
for index,val in enumerate(scraped_items):
    dic[f'Copy {index}'] = val

{'locale': 'some place',
 'title': 'some site',
 'Copy 0': '<p>First copy block</p>',
 'Copy 1': '<p>Second copy block</p>'}
```

Comment: I had a feeling I could use `enumerate` as well but wasn't sure it would yield these results, or rather, I wasn't sure how to go about applying the method. Thank you for the example.